# Invalid schema for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, strongloop

I used loopback to set up an API, hitting a mongodb on my local. All good, and it's all running properly. Then I tried to move it to bluemix. When I got to the step for slc arc and using the composer, every time I try to check the db connection, I get an error that says, "invalid schema, expected mongodb".

This is the full error from the strongloop composer:

```
Oops! Something is wrong
invalid schema, expected mongodb

Message: invalid schema, expected mongodb
Request: /workspace/api/DataSourceDefinitions/server.mongoDB/testConnection
Staus: 500
Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
    at module.exports (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:20:11)
    at connect (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:125:16)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:109:3)
    at MongoDB.connect (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:113:25)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:70:26)
    at DataSource.setup (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:332:17)
    at new DataSource (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:109:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:349:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:415:19)
    at EventEmitter.app.dataSource (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:222:12)
```

I tried fiddling with the datasources.fig.json so it looked the same as the datasources.json, but that didn't seem to do a thing. (Details omitted for sake of showing, replaced with [generic].)

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mongoDB": {
    "host": "[appname].mybluemix.net",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "[appname].mybluemix.net",
    "database": "strongloop",
    "password": "[password]",
    "name": "mongoDB",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "user": "[username]"
  }
}
```

Worst of all, now I can't even run it on my local! If I try slc run like usual, I get the same error. Here's the console output:

```
/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:20
    throw new Error('invalid schema, expected mongodb'); 
    ^

Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
    at module.exports (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:20:11)
    at connect (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:125:16)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:109:3)
    at MongoDB.connect (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:113:25)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:70:26)
    at DataSource.setup (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:332:17)
    at new DataSource (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:109:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:349:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:415:19)
    at EventEmitter.app.dataSource (/Users/kusuriuri/Webworks/charapi/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:222:12)
```

Nothing anywhere is telling me how to fix this, or what's even caused it, and I don't know why I can't even run the app on my local anymore. What went wrong, and how do I get this thing working?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to create a Mongo database accessible over the web. You could try MongoDB by Compose.  You could also reveal the MongoDB instance on your local machine.

The host/port/url and other credentials for your MongoDB connnection are not the same as your Bluemix application URL. Rather, those credentials should point to an existing MongoDB instance.

Input the credentials to your MongoDB instance into your `datasources.json` file.  Whether your LoopBack application is running locally or on Bluemix, it should be able to connect to your MongoDB service.

Also, try using Arc (`slc arc`) to create your database connection; you can easily test that your LoopBack application will be able to access the database with the `Test Connection` button.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. "Test Connection" is something that allows you to get a binary response on whether or not you have properly specified your credentials.  A failure to connect implies that your credentials were incorrect; in your case, your credentials were not referring to a MongoDB instance, but a Bluemix application.  This would allow you to identify your faulty credentials before pushing to Bluemix.

I fail to understand how building from scratch solves your problem, as you still will not be able to connect to your MongoDB instance on Bluemix with your incorrect credentials.

Comment: The url should be something like `mongodb://host:port/db`.

Comment: Building from scratch solves two problems: it lets me see what loopback was hiding under the hood, AND it let me cut a massive amount of overhead from loopback. I mean, I just about maxed out my free 2gig on that one upload. I like the idea of Bluemix, but it and Strongloop (esp Strongloop) have a ways to go, from a user perspective. For now, I'll stick with heroku & from-scratch express. Thanks for the help, though!